# Problem with mapping file (relationship)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping

I just started to learn Nhibernate. I have problem with mapping (exact -  relationship).
I have two table:

Table1 (DIC_TOWN)

```
TOWN_ID
   1
   2
   3
```

Table 2(DIC_TOWN_STRINGS)

```
TOWN_ID    LANG_ID     TOWN_NAME
   1       1            CityName
   1       2            CityName
   2       1            CityName
   2       2            CityName
```

My class:

```
public class TownS
    {
        public virtual int TownId { get; set; }

        public virtual Languages LangId { get; set; }

        public virtual string TownName { get; set; }

    }
```

**EDIT:**

My mapping file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="EArchive.Data" namespace="EArchive.Data.Class">
  <class name="TownS" table="DIC_TOWN_STRINGS" lazy="false">   
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="TownId" column="TOWN_ID" />
      <key-property name="LangId" column="LANG_ID" />
    </composite-id>    

    <property name="TownName" column="TOWN_NAME" />
    <many-to-one name="LangId" column="LANG_ID"/>  
  </class>  
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Help me to write mapping file. And if possible, with explanation. Thanks.

Comment: What are the classes `TownS` and `Languages`?

Answer (score 2):

The table Dic_Town_Strings should have a composite key composed from both town_id and lang_id
And the LangId property should be mapped by a many-to-one relationship to your Language class mapping (or change the TownS LangId property declaration to int instead of Language)

Comment: :corrected, but i have the following error: could not determine a property type for: LangId

Comment: Your many-to-one mapping is incorrect - you didn't specify the object type (is the Language class even mapped???)  
Please look [here](http://ayende.com/blog/3938/nhibernate-mapping-many-to-one) for how to do many-to-one mapping properly

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
public class Town
{
    public virtual int TownId { get; private set; }

    public virtual Dict<Language, string> AllNames { get; private set; }

    public virtual string TownName 
    { 
      get { return AllNames[CurrentLanguage]; }
    }

}
```

Mapping:

```
<class name="Town">
<id ...>
<map name="AllNames">
  <key column="TOWN_ID"/>
  <index column="LANG_ID"/>
  <element column="TOWN_NAME" />
</map>
```

There is no composite key around, everything is straight forward ...

Comment: There are composite keys,in the Table2: TownId and LangId

Comment: @user348173: yes, of course, but not mapped as id. This is important. Composite-ids should be avoided.